# How to replace hub motor cable in e-bike?

Tags: electric-bike, cable

[image: picture of damaged e-bike hub motor, power cable, and spokes]
The hub motor wires are cut from near the axle and looks like I can't repair it without completely replacing it. The motor is similar to [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33007009169.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000060.1.13b848d8JLwYKU&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller&scm=1007.13339.146401.0&scm_id=1007.13339.146401.0&scm-url=1007.13339.146401.0&pvid=e19a23cb-82c4-4cc7-ad4c-9162bb6a1e9a&_t=gps-id:pcDetailBottomMoreThisSeller,scm-url:1007.13339.146401.0,pvid:e19a23cb-82c4-4cc7-ad4c-9162bb6a1e9a,tpp_buckets:668%230%23131923%2358_668%23808%234093%23860_668%23888%233325%2320_668%232846%238108%23134_668%232717%237559%2386_668%231000022185%231000066055%230_668%233468%2315613%23493) one on Ali Express. I failed  to open the motor because the screws are so tight and rusted. I am thinking of cutting some part of the rod and join the wires. This seems an easier but not a good solution. Any advices?

**Update**:

I was able to get my motor working by cutting the cable from near the sensor board, pulling the cable inside the motor through the shaft and rejoining/soldering from where it was originally cut. This shortened my cable few inches and it was barely reachable to the controller. See the picture below. I wanted to know if the cable can be completely replaced with no need for these joins but it's not easy as the cable was the part of the motor coil itself.

[image]

Comment: At the very least, you will need to provide more detail. Hub manufacturer and model and high-quality close-up photos of all relevant parts, including both ends of the damaged cable, to start with. It would also help if you explain what research you've done already; have you contacted the manufacturer to see whether they will sell you replacement parts? Have you attempted disassembly of either the hub motor or the controller?

Comment: What kind of cable is it. Just a twin wire current connection or a multi wired cable delivering power to the motor and feed-back info to the controller?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I've updated the question. Please let me know if I can provide more details.

Comment: @Carel Motor has 8 wires and I'm not really sure if it's a multi wired cable.

Comment: You'll need to rejoin the 8 wires, matching the colour on both sides.  This is more electrical work than bicycles.

Comment: You need to disassemble the motor and replace the cables.  Requires some electrical skills.

Comment: This appears to be a design weakness too - you should consider how to mitigate this repair from becoming an annual thing.

Comment: Regarding you not being able to open your screws, have you tried applying plenty of WD40. Usually works for me with rusted screws on any sort of application. Alternatively you could drill them out, but be sure to have proper equipment for that or be looking at buying a new motor.

Comment: Based on your new photo, that's a 3 phase motor, and the phases are labelled A/B/C with Ground as the return.  The 5V line is probably there to run some sensors, and perhaps a front light as well.   The smaller ABC lines are probably sensors of some sort associated with each phase.   +1 for coming back and giving an update.

Comment: There's a whole lot of bare wire exposed there - that's just asking for more problems in the future.

Comment: @Criggie Thanks for all the details about wires. I'm not sure what ABC, GND and 5v are for. Since they are connected to sensor board, I guess they all have something to do with controlling motor speed and such things. I'm curious to know what each wire does though. Thanks again for your comment.

Comment: @AndyP Yes, I feel that too. This is what I could do with my limited knowledge and skills. But now I'm able to ride my bicycle like before.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a motor broken during shipment (luckily the manufacturer sent me a new one). I tried to fix the broken one by replacing the cable, but it's quite hard to do, because the space inside the housing is quite small, and when I tested the motor it worked for a while until the housing, by rubbing the cable, shortened the sensor cable, and broke the sensor board in the motor. I could reasonably run it sensorless, but you need a sensorless controller if this happen. Long story short is not easy at all, I'm quite good in soldering but failed in this regard. And disassembling the motor, at least with my geared unit, is not so easy as well, so if you have nothing to lose you might try it, but be prepared for a long evening of struggling.

Comment: Hello! I first struggled with opening the motor screws manually, then bought an electric screw driver which helped. I've never done soldering before but somehow managed. Please see the image in my updated question. It's a dirty work but I'm happy it's working now. The motor has a bad design and bad cable protection. I wish it was easy to replace the entire cable really easily. I'm sure there must be such ideal motors somewhere.

Comment: Well, not a masterpiece, but if it works... I see some cable without protection, I suggest to protect at least with electrical tape or hotglue, better with heatshrink tube, because the case of the motor is conductive and might short circuit everything.